# forwarding all traffic to folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, forwarding

I am currently using the following to forward all incoming traffic to the cms folder in root.

```
<?php header("location:/cms"); ?>
```

Is there anyway to keep the url as the sites root.
i.e. mydomain.com not mydomain.com/cms

any pointers appreciated,

Comment: use `mod_rewrite` or change your document root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using `mod_rewrite`. I think this works (put this inside `.htaccess` under document root):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cms/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cms/$1
```

Also you can just change document root `DocumentRoot "/home/www/mysite"` to `DocumentRoot "/home/www/mysite/cms"`

Comment: I'm sure that the single rule without condition would case infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

I think mode_rewrite is one of the best solution for this. You can put the following code into your .htaccess file under root directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?yourprimarydomain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?yourmaindomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subfolder/index.php [L]
```